# What is wrong with this TCP interaction?

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp

I have TCPServer.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket tcp = new ServerSocket(1387);

        while (true) {
            Socket request = tcp.accept();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(request.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Request count: " + sc.nextLine());
            out.writeBytes("send another request please");
        }
    }
}
```

and `pythonClient.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket, time, sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((sys.argv[1], 1387))
count = 0
while True:
   count += 1
   sock.sendall(str(count) + "\n")
   time.sleep(1)
   data = sock.recv(1024)
   print "received:\n", str(data)
```

I am running both on the same host and was expecting to receive "Request count: x" every second with an incremented `x` value in the console of the TCPServer and

```
received:
send another request please
```

every second in the terminal that is running pythonClient.py. However, all I get is "Request count: 1" in java console and nothing else. In the terminal, I get:

```
received:
s
received:
end another request please
```

Why is this not working as expected? Why is it all locked up after one iteration and why did the first response from the server get accepted as two different messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java code is expecting to receive a new connection each time around the loop and interact with each one once. Your Python code is making one connection and trying to interact with it repeatedly. These models don't match up - you will need to change one.

The easiest one to change would be the Python code. We can make a new connection each time around the loop as follows:

```
count = 0
while True:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((sys.argv[1], 1387))
    count += 1
    sock.sendall(str(count) + "\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print "received:\n", str(data)
```